# Integrate Liferay with CAS and SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, liferay-6, saml-2.0, cas, opensaml

We have a requirement where user needs to login to portal with CAS (but SAML way). User can also login via login portlet of liferay.
We have few apps hosted on `Intranet` and few on `Extranet`. When user is in our office network, he should be able to login to all the apps via SSO. This includes apps which are hosted on extranet as well.
To achive this we want to use `SAML with CAS`.
By doing some research I understand that in this case CAS would be my IDP i.e. Identity provider and my apps on extranet would be SP i.e. service provider
 Any idea how to proceed with it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I  have to do the same thing but using a LDAP too ...

I'm following [this cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/packtlib/book/Web%20Development/9781782164289) to achieve that, the [second chapter](https://www.packtpub.com/packtlib/book/Web%20Development/9781782164289/2) talks about `Authentication and Registration Process`

I hope this would be helpful!!